# In which file do I need to add an override for the jetty port when running a lift webapp in dev mode from sbt?

Tags: scala, lift

This page:
http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Using_SBT
describes how to override the jetty port for lift webapps:

```
override val jettyPort = 8081
```

but doesn't state the file that this override should be defined in.

Answer (score 6):

In the `project/build/ProjectNameProject.scala` file:

```
import sbt._

class ProjectNameProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultWebProject(info) {
    // other configuration
    override val jettyPort = 8081
}
```

The `jettyPort` is defined in the `DefaultProject.scala` file of SBT.

See here: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#_gvea9IT4iU/trunk/src/main/scala/sbt/DefaultProject.scala&q=%22jettyPort%22&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc