# Specifying the Jetty port in SBT 0.10

Tags: scala, jetty, sbt, embedded-jetty

I need to run the embedded Jetty on port different to the default 8080, using SBT 0.10
The question was answered here for SBT 0.7 - [In which file do I need to add an override for the jetty port when running a lift webapp in dev mode from sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722356/in-which-file-do-i-need-to-add-an-override-for-the-jetty-port-when-running-a-lift).
I can find no reference to do the same for SBT 0.10 
I am using the Full configuration (Build.scala) for multi modules and not quick the sbt dsl.

Comment: Where did you put "jettyPort"? I put it in Build.scala and got "reassignment to val". Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SBT 0.10 Jetty support no longer goes as a part of the build tool, but rather shipped as a **[plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin)**. In order to change the port, you'll have to initialize `jettyPort` setting with your value:

```
jettyPort := 1111
```

Or, if you're running from the console:

```
set jettyPort := 1111
session save
```

See plugin instructions for more details.

Answer (score 6):

For sbt 0.11.2 , you specify

```
port in container.Configuration := 8081
```

in build.sbt